# What does `((,) e` mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass

I'm reading the [typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Functor) on Haskell wiki. When I came across the typeclass `((,) e)` which is an instance of functor, I was quite confused. According to the author

> `((,) e)` represents a container which holds an “annotation” of type e along with the actual value it holds.

However, I can't quite understand the meaning of this sentence since I can only see a sectioned tuple here. I also searched this typeclass on Hoogle but found nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`((,) e)` is not a typeclass; it's just a type. And indeed, it *is* a sectioned tuple. The idea here is that you can think of `(e, a)` as a "container" holding a value of type `a` and an "annotation" of type `e`. The `fmap` for `((,) e)` modifies the *values*, but not the *annotations*. In the "functor as container" analogy, the annotation is part of the *container*, rather than part of its *contents*.

Let's consider a sort of tree:

```
data Tree f a
  = Leaf
  | Node (Tree f a) (f a) (Tree f a)

instance Functor f => Functor (Tree f) where
  fmap _ Leaf = Leaf
  fmap f (Node l fa r) = Node (fmap f l) (fmap f fa) (fmap f r)
```

What do these look like? `Tree Identity a` is a plain binary tree of elements of type `a`. It could represent, e.g., a set of values. `Tree ((,) k) a`, on the other hand, is a binary tree of *pairs*. It could represent a map from keys of type `k` to values of type `a`. Mapping over the tree with `fmap` will modify the values, but leave the keys alone.

Comment: Awesome! It seems that `(e, a)` can be seen as the computation of `a` in the context of `e`.

Comment: This is called the "writer monad", in case you want to look up more about this. (Strictly speaking I should point out it's only a monad if `e` is an instance of the `Monoid` class.) It's one of the standard Haskell monad instances, so you can find lots of information about it, eg https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#The_Writer_monad and http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html